# How does PHP readdir/opendir sort

Tags: php, sorting, opendir, scandir

I wondered how come that when calling following code the file(name)s in the array are always sorted differently. How does PHP `opendir` sort the files and how can I change it in the system without having to put it inside an array first which I then sort?

```
$dh  = opendir($dir);  
    do {
        $files_in_dir[] = $filename;
    }
    while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh)));
```

Comment: "array are always sorted differently" ??

Comment: also, why have you introduced a bug?? the manual has a perfectly good example of how to use it.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath what do you mean?

Comment: What do you mean by "what do you mean"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The entries are returned in the order in which they are stored by the filesystem.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

Answer (score 1):

As a suggestion, use `PHP`'s **[scandir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)** function instead, as `PHP`'s official document defines it:

> **scandir — List files and directories inside the specified path**

And also supports sorting.

> By default, the sorted order is alphabetical in ascending order. If the optional sorting_order is set to SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING, then the sort order is alphabetical in descending order. If it is set to SCANDIR_SORT_NONE then the result is unsorted.